# RecylerView height doesn't filled when use inside another RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` as child of another `RecyclerView`, But when I add data to second `RecyclerView` it doesn't show anything. I should say when I set height of second `RecyclerView` to (e.g. 100dp) it shows some content of it.

How should I solve problem?

-main xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#1E88E5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- item xml

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:clickable="true"
      android:id="@+id/lla2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:text="Medium Text"
          android:id="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view13"
          android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view13"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ib2"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view13"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view13"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ib2" />

      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
          android:id="@+id/view13"
          android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ib2"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ib2" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recycler_view6"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_below="@+id/view13" />


      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
          android:alpha="0.5"
          android:id="@+id/ib2"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
          android:src="@drawable/note"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:id="@+id/imageButton"
          android:alpha="0.1"
          android:layout_below="@+id/ib2"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
          android:src="@drawable/bookmark"
          android:alpha="0.5"
          android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Comment: please post the xml.

Comment: @LucasPaolillo I posted xml

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a LinearLayout manager?  If so, that's your problem.  It wasn't that good at measuring height with wrap_content until recently.  If you're using a relatively new version of the recyclerview library (and are using a LinearLayoutManager), make a call to this:

`yourLinearLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);`

That will enable auto measure and cause it to work with wrap_content.  Also, since this is a nested recyclerview, don't forget to enable nested scrolling.

Comment: I am using             GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, items.get(0).getTranslate().size() > 1 ? 2 : 1);

Comment: GridLayoutManager also has the autoMesure opt-in API.  I would go ahead and call that on your nested recyclerview's layout manager and see if that fixes your issue.  Called same way as in my initial reply.

Comment: I tested but nothing happened.